# How to unhide files on Mac?

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

I did: `chflags hidden /Users/MyUser/Library/(theareawheremyfileis)` and it hid my file.
I did this in Terminal, now I typed in `... unhidden ...` and I can't seem a way to unhide the file I hid.

Along with that, I want a way to see **all** hidden files just using a terminal command, no matter hidden by the computer or hidden by the user using chflags.

So I need two different things.

Answer (score 27):

`chflags nohidden` will unhide a hidden file/folder.

You can press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to show all files regardless of any other state (in macOS Sierra and above.)

Alternatively, you can run the command `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true` then relaunch Finder (any version of macOS.)

Answer (score 13):

It's `chflags nohidden <filename>`

Answer (score 5):

There is a handy Finder keyboard shortcut to toggle showing hidden files and folders:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Or, if you prefer the `defaults` route:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Both have the same effect, though the keyboard shortcut does change the value of the `default`.

Neither of these will change any files' hidden status, but will show all hidden files and folders in Finder:

They appear "washed out" so you can differentiate them from non-hidden files.

[image: macOS hidden folders appearance]