# How do I unhide the desktop folder in my home folder?

Tags: finder, big-sur, invisible-files

I've tried [How to unhide files on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309450/how-to-unhide-files-on-mac), and [chflags nohidden not unhiding hidden files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400376/chflags-nohidden-not-unhiding-hidden-files) to no avail. I want to unhide `~/desktop` while I have iCloud desktop turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can unhide folders, you cannot unhide the Desktop or Documents folder when using Desktop iCloud. Both it and the Documents folder are hidden by having the com.apple.iCloud.desktop extended attribute applied, remove that attribute and you are no longer using iCloud Desktop/Documents folders.

You could do something like `ln -s "$HOME/Desktop" "$HOME/Desktop "` (note the space) if you want to see a folder in your home folder.

Comment: When I type that in it just says dquote, what do I put there?

Comment: @unbeatable101, I have fixed the _shell command_ in lbutlr's answer so it would actually create a _symbolic link_. As it was originally written it would not work that way as quotes placed around `~` keeps it from expanding properly. `$HOME` is the better way in this use case.

Comment: thanks, forgot that ~ don’t expand in double quotes. ~/Desktop and ~/“Desktop “ should also work.

Answer (score -2):

Press ⇧ Shift + ⌘ Command + . . This key combination will display any hidden folders in your Mac's hard drive. Any hidden folders or files will appear as grayed-out. This keyboard shortcut can be done from any Finder window.

Comment: Yes that works, but is not what I wanted, that will make all folders hidden, I just wanted `~/desktop` unhidden.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! The OP stated "I've tried [How to unhide files on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309450/how-to-unhide-files-on-mac)," which happens to have that _keyboard shortcut_, so repeating it as an answer makes no sense! Please take the time to read and understand the question being asked before posting your answer.